# Where to store view parameters in an AJAX session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

In a non-AJAX web app, the URL would contain my view parameters (e.g. mysite?page=2&sort=name). In an AJAX app, where do I store the same info? In the Session object?

Comment: What kind of app are you writing? The method you use will depend on what you want to do.

Comment: Just about any typical Rails app. Let's assume a simple app that lists books, for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to know how to pass additional params with an AJAX call. This really depends on how you're formulating the AJAX call.

If you're using the built-in Rails helpers, you can pass additional params inside the `url_for` helper. For example, lets say that you have a `products` route and you want to AJAX load a list of all products. The `link_to` helper might look something like this (Rails 3.2)

```
link_to "All Products", products_path(:page => 2, :sort => "name"), :remote => true
```

If on the other hand you're using a JavaScript framework like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), you can pass additional params using the `data` option. For example

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/products",
    data: {
        page: 2,
        sort: "name"
    },
    success: function(data) {
        // handle success
    },
    failure: function(data) {
        // handle failure
    }
 });
```

Storing this data (page, sort, etc.) can be done multiple ways also. The easiest way would be to store this data inside a JavaScript variable.

```
window.page = 2;
window.sort = "name";
```

Another solution is to store this information in the `data` attribute of a particular DOM element on the page. For example, if you have a `<div id='products'>` that contains a list of the paginated, sorted products, you could store the information like this (jQuery)

```
$("#products").data("page", 2);
$("#products").data("sort", "name");
```

Comment: Thanks for this! But what I want to know is where would I temporarily *store* the current settings (page, sort, etc)? In a non-AJAX app, the browser URL would be updated when changing page/sorting, etc. But not in AJAX. Please advice!

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you don't structure you're requests differently for AJAX in Rails. You'll just add the `:remote => true` attribute to your link or form, then make the controller action respond_to js

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end
```

And then put your_action.js.erb in your views and write javascript that updates the dom in the appropriate way.

Comment: I got that, but what about parameter values for filtering, sorting?